# Any way to create a "state" listener instead of an "event" listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that I can add a `click` or `change` listener on a checkbox. The handler changes the `disabled` `prop`of a button to `true` when the checkbox is unchecked. That's easy.

But rather than having this be event-driven, is there a way to have this be "state" driven?

If the "state" of the checkbox is unchecked, the "state" of the button will always be disabled. It doesn't matter what kind of event triggers the state change. If the checkbox is in one state, then the button is always in a corresponding state. That's it.

Here's an example of standard event-driven code where a checkout button should be disabled as long as the terms and conditions checkbox is unchecked.

```
  $('input[name="terms-and-conditons"]').change(function(e, tmpl){
    if(e.target.checked === true){
      $('#checkout-button').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $('#checkout-button').prop("disabled", true);
    };
  });
```

Unfortunately this doesn't take into account initial states, since it requires an event to happen for something else to happen. On page load, if the checkbox is unchecked, the button could still be enabled, unless care is taken to remember to set the initial state of the button to disabled:

```
  // setting the initial state
  $('#checkout-button').prop("disabled", true);
  $('input[name="terms-and-conditons"]').prop("checked", false);

  $('input[name="terms-and-conditons"]').change(function(e, tmpl){
    if(e.target.checked === true){
      $('#checkout-button').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $('#checkout-button').prop("disabled", true);
    };
  });
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a "state listener." No matter what event happens (even if there isn't an event, like a default value on pageload), the button state will always be in lockstep with the checkbox state. It could be changed via a click, space key press, change event, someone just editing the HTML directly in Chrome Console, or it might just initially load in some kind of state. The point is that things just *are*. And the state of certain things can automatically change with the state of those other things.

Comment: There is no such feature like you are asking built into a browser.  You will have to implement it with your own JS by observing all possible events that indicate a change to the relevant state.

Comment: That's what I've been doing. So the solution is really just to register a whole bunch of event listeners and handlers for a single ID or class of checkboxes and to hope that you haven't forgotten to account for some event?

Comment: In modern browsers, could a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on a specific attribute be a more generic change listener?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `trigger` to force the event handler to run on page load. You can also change the button state using the checkbox state.

```
// setting the initial state
$('#checkout-button').prop("disabled", true);

$('input[name="terms-and-conditons"]').on('change', function() {
    $('#checkout-button').prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
}).trigger('change');
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: In this case I don't want to use event handlers. Events are specific. A `change` event doesn't fire at the same time as a `keyup` event, even though the state of something is changing. Take a real-world analogy: "When a car hits a tree it becomes damaged and the insurance pays out money." That's event-driven. I want something like "Car now damaged. Insurance pays."

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny As jfriend said above, `There is no such feature like you are asking built into a browser. You will have to implement it with your own JS by observing all possible events that indicate a change to the relevant state` You've to use `event-driven` programming

Answer (score 2):

Hi dude i thing what you want is the like

i think you need to refer

**Publish/Subscribe** Pattern or **observer pattern**

http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

this may help you to what you want

and one thing i want to add that **Only chorme browser supports the .Observe()** Method for detail study for that you could refer

**http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es7/observe/**

Comment: Thanks. I've been using MeteorJS so I'm pretty familiar with this pub/sub and observer pattern. So far it gets really really close to what I'm looking for. In fact, I can code in a state-driven style when I'm working on the JS code, but as soon as I touch the DOM, I have to revert back to an event-driven style, if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

hi you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/elviz/gg5r92q0/1/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   var is_click = $("#myCheckbox").is(':checked');

  if(is_click == false){
     $("#checkout-button").prop('disabled', true);
   }else{
   $("#checkout-button").prop('disabled', false);
    }

    $("#myCheckbox").click(function(){

    var is_click = $("#myCheckbox").is(':checked')

        if(is_click == false){
              $("#checkout-button").prop('disabled', true);
        }else{
            $("#checkout-button").prop('disabled', false);
        }

 }); 


 });
```

Comment: the state of button is depending on the state of your checkbox